# How would I initialize this array in constructor

Tags: java

I am trying to construct a table to size of 10 that I have initialized.

```
private LinkedList<MapEntry<K, V>>[] table;
```

I have tried `table = new LinkedList<MapEntry<K, V>>[];` and also `table = new LinkedList<MapEntry<K, V>>()[];`

None of these are working and I need help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ouch. i would look for a different type. that design looks messed up

Comment: I am trying to create my own hash map using chaining so the arrays of linked lists is crucial.

Comment: From which package you have imported MapEntry.

Comment: java.util.map                                                     public  class MapEntry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this --

```
table  = (LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>[])new LinkedList[10];
```

For more understanding look at the old ques

[How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Comment: Im not getting any errors so I going to go with this. Thanks!